# When click, tr should show its own expanding row

Tags: jquery

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljv7nb8p/1/)

On Jsfiddle it is not working as my local machine.

On local machine, the only thing is that when click on 'highlight', it will show all 'more' rows at one go which is not right. Even tried '.next('more') but it seemed not to be working.

What it should be: hiding 'more' till 'highlight' row is clicked, then expand its own 'more' row. If other 'highlight' row is clicked, the previous expanded row should close and the current expand row show.

HTML

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr class="highlight">
    <td>
Test 1 
    </td>
    <td>
      Test 2
    </td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Test4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="more" style="border-top:1px solid red">
      test test

    </td>
  </tr>
      <tr class="highlight">
    <td>
Test 1 
    </td>
    <td>
      Test 2
    </td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Test4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="more" style="border-top:1px solid red">
      test test

    </td>
  </tr>


</tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery

```
$(".highlight").each(function(e){

    $(this).click(function(e){

      if($('.more').hasClass('block')){
        $('.more').removeClass('block');
        alert('removed');
      }
      else{
        $('.more').addClass('block');
      }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.more{display:none;}
.block(display:block!important}
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to include jQuery in your fiddle. Then, you have a syntax error in your CSS.

```
.block {
    display: block !important;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Ljv7nb8p/4/)

---

That said, your code could probably be much simpler:

```
$(".highlight").click(function() {
    $(this).next('tr.more').toggle();
    $('tr.more').not( $(this).next() ).hide();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Ljv7nb8p/8)

Note that I've moved the `.more` class to the row element.

Comment: thanks so much. duh me on css part. one more thing -- colspan="4" seems not be working? Because the border red should be following the length of the parents' row. Any idea?

Comment: It does for me in Chrome.

Comment: sorry but toggle() does not work as I wanted it to go. When click the highlight, then its more row will expand. then if i click next highlight, the previous expanding row should close.

Comment: It does for me in Chrome.

Comment: Notice that I did make an update. Are you looking at the most recent version of my answer?

Comment: many thanks! this.next().hide() not working - duh me. but thanks alot